# how do I sum each column based on condition of another column without iterating over the columns in pandas datframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sum

I have a data frame as below:

```
    Preg  Glucose  BloodPressure  SkinThickness  Insulin  Outcome  
0    1.0     85.0           66.0           29.0      0.0    0.0   
1    8.0    183.0           64.0            0.0      0.0    0.0   
2    1.0     89.0           66.0           23.0     94.0    1.0   
3    0.0    137.0           40.0           35.0    168.0    1.0   
4    5.0    116.0           74.0            0.0      0.0    1.0
```

I would like a pythonic way to sum each column in separate based on a condition of one of the columns. I could do it with iterating over the df columns, but I'm sure there is a better way I'm not familiar with.

In specific to the data I have, I'd like to sum each column values if at the last column 'Outcome' is equal to 1. In the end, I should get as below:

```
    Preg   Glucose BloodPressure  SkinThickness  Insulin  Outcome  
0    6.0     342.0         180.0           58.0    262.0    0.0
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution to get the expected output:

```
sum_df = df.loc[df.Outcome == 1.0].sum().to_frame().T
sum_df.Outcome = 0.0
```

Output:

```
   Preg  Glucose  BloodPressure  SkinThickness  Insulin  Outcome
0   6.0    342.0          180.0           58.0    262.0      0.0
```

> Documentation:
>
> - [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html): access a group of rows / columns by labels or boolean array
> - [sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html): sum by default over all columns and return a Series indexed by the columns.
> - [to_frame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html): convert a Series to a DataFrame.
> - [.T](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html): accessor the transpose function, transpose the DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

use `np.where`

```
df1[np.where(df1['Outcome'] == 1,True,False)].sum().to_frame().T
```

**Output**

```
  Preg  Glucose  BloodPressure  SkinThickness  Insulin  Outcome
0   6.0    342.0          180.0           58.0    262.0      3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Will these work for you?

```
df1.loc[~(df1['Outcome'] == 0)].groupby('Outcome').agg('sum').reset_index()
```

or

```
df1.loc[df1.Outcome == 1.0].sum().to_frame().T
```